# get a column count without "NaN"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

How do I count the number of columns without `NaN` ?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'age', 'favorite_color', 'grade','NaN'])
print(len(df.columns))
```

**Output:** 5

But looking Output: 4

Comment: your answer is not clear, 
if you do `print(len(df,colunms)-1)` it will give you 4

Comment: `columns` in `pd.DataFrame()` refers to the labels of each column. So are you trying to filter columns by name?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I count the number of columns without NaN

Few additional ways are:

*Method1* :

```
len(df.columns ^ ['NaN'])
```

*Method2* [`pd.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
len(df.columns.difference(['NaN']))
```

*Method3* `set`: (almost same as 2)

```
len(set(df.columns)-{'NaN'})
```

Comment: Hi Anky . thanks for sharing this. its very useful.

Comment: Hi what if there is "np.null" instead of {'Nan'}

Comment: @GovindaRaju can you update the example in the question? for clarity

Comment: a b c d f g  # Group1
1 1 3 6 8 1
2 2 4 7 9 2
3 3 5 8 0 2
     
     
a b c d  #Group 2
1 3 3 3  
2 3 4 3  
3 4 4 3                     

Hi Assume The above table as importing from csv file .once its importing automatically blank cells as replaced "NaN" as we know that, if i divided this as group1 and group2 , if i want take column count of Group2,its showes 6 **instead of correct answer 4**

Comment: Please update the question with proper formatting. data in comments aren't readable @GovindaRaju

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
res = [x for x in df.columns if str(x) not in ['nan','NaN','NAN'] ]
print(res)
#['name', 'age', 'favorite_color', 'grade']
print(len(res)
#4
```

Comment: Hi Tawab_Shakeel, thanks for response . its works fine

Comment: great @GovindaRaju if you find it helpful upvote or approve it

Answer (score 0):

Use basic python to get the result:-

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['name', 'age', 'favorite_color', 'grade','NaN'])
col = df.columns

count = 0
for var in col:
    if var not in  ['NaN', 'nan']:
        count+=1
print(f"The length of columns without NaN values is\t {count} ")
```

Output:

```
The length of columns without NaN values is  4
```

Comment: Hi Rahul Thanks for reply . but looking for short code

Comment: @GovindaRaju you can write the whole code in one line as  `print(len([var for var in df.columns if var not in ['NaN','nan']]))`

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to drop columns whose name is np.nan or NaN, respectively; try this:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.notnull()]
df = df.loc[:, (filter(lambda x: x != 'NaN',df.columns))]
print(len(df.columns))
```

On the other side, you maight want to drop columns that include Nan:

```
# drop the columns where at least one element is NaN:
df.dropna(axis=1)

# drop the columns where all elements are NaN:
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

Comment: Hello Nadjar, thanks for your response . But looking for count for column

Comment: you're welcome. you can now print after applying filter. check it, please.